# Trying to fetch a PDF file from Firebase Storage byt getting a CORS error

Tags: reactjs, cors

I am using a MERN stack for my web application. I am currently trying to fetch a PDF file from my firebase storage but I am having a problem with CORS error. Here is my code

Here is my code:

Here is the Error:

mydocuments:1 Access to fetch at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bfpncrdoctracking.appspot.com/o/1706324416273-2k0p58lue1f.pdf?alt=media&token=94cfc3a0-32ba-489a-88b9-571b16ea6b4b' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

for my backend I also use app.use(cors()); as a middleware.

I already tried to use different packages for PDF viewer and I also tried to access different web storage for PDF but still giving me a CORS error. I also tried to use Localstorage and still have the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.